# Does "fare" apply to non-persons?

Tags: differences, american-english, synonyms

If one pays for transportation of oneself a *fare* has been paid. What is paid if the transportation is of a non-person object (a parcel, a letter, a vegetable, a box of rocks)?

Comment: Here's [fare for a package](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QVlNAAAAYAAJ&q=%22fare+for+a+package%22&dq=%22fare+for+a+package%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Q-oiT_2JMoOY8QPGs9zgBw&ved=0CFEQ6AEwAA), but probably you'd usually pay the **carriage** for non-humans (especially if unaccompanied).

Comment: Thats kind of what I was thinking as freight would seem to only apply to a larger/consigned service. However, 'carriage' would seem to be the act of conveyance. 'Carriage Fee/Charge/Price' would be less ambiguous but I am looking for a single word (to be used as a label for an amount charged for an instance of conveyance.)

Comment: Google Books has plenty of instances of [pay (the) carriage for (something)](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=texas+holdem&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbo=1&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min%3A1900%2Ccd_max%3A1999&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22pay+carriage+for%22&psj=1&oq=%22pay+carriage+for%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=5653l6132l4l6627l4l4l0l0l0l2l406l838l1.1.1.0.1l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=57fad0bae3cb2180&biw=1158&bih=696). There's no requirement for it to be followed by *fee/price*.

Comment: Through the post, it would be *postage.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'll buy it. Post your solution as an Answer & I'll accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: *carriage* sounds more like BrE to me, and a quick ngrams check seems to bear that out. Americans would be more likely to call it *shipping*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the manner in which the item is transported, you could pay

- *freight*
- *shipping*
- *postage*
- *carriage*
- *haulage*
- *delivery*
- any of the above in conjunction with *fee*, *charge*, etc.

Comment: carriage is the word I was looking for I believe